# Mongoose middleware Update or Save

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I was wondering if I can do something like this in mongoose.

```
schema.pre('save' || 'update' , function (next) {
    //do something
});
```

Like trigger this middleware either for save or update actions.

Thank you

Comment: No. But you can declare a `function` externally and define it to both handlers. `.pre()` itself is a function and it's first argument is the "hook" to attach to, and not a "condition" or code. So `function onSaveOrUpdate(next) { .. }; schema.pre('save', onSaveOrUpdate); schema.pre('update', onSaveOrUpdate);`

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach. The thing is that I had to pass 'this' in the parameters every time and other variables too. But well I think we can live with that. Thank you

Comment: If you are passing `this` then you are doing it wrong. In a middleware hook the `this` will refer to the current instance, so if you are passing in something else then your code is likely to break. Did you use `function()` or did you think you'd be clever and use and "arrow" `=>` function? If you did the latter then, it actually wasn't clever, since this is a place where you would not use one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as it will always result in the hook being made as a pre-save hook.  Not because of Mongoose, but because of how ECMAScript logical operators work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR

If you want a pre-save and a pre-validate hook, you would need to create them separately.